# I want to use the color of one volume to color a mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, shaders, volumetrics, custom-attributes

Is there a way to use the color of a volume object to shade it?

I haven't found anything online or when checking shaders and geo-nodes.

[image: mesh inside, and green points showing the volume I want to use for coloring the mesh]

Does anyone have an idea to solve this? I didn't understand on how I could use the tools in shaders and geonodes for achieving this (volume info, object info, texture coordinate etc.)

Basically I want to get the color of the mesh by sampling the volume at that point. Or by transferring the attribute of the points (when reading the volume as vertices) to the mesh.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "by sampling checking for the volume"? Or what do you mean by " the color of a volume object"? The color of a volume object is whatever color you assign to it. So of course you could use that color for other objects as well. Or do you mean the density of the volume? The density at any point in the volume is given by a float value in the 0 to 1 range. So the _Density_ output of a _Volume Info_ node gives you these values.

Comment: First point was a mistake.
My problem is the transfer to another object. I can either use the density to color the volume (which I have from a 4D-data-array), or import the array as a grid of vertices with the density as attribute. 

I need a way to transfer this to a mesh. 

In principle I can use the volume info node to color the volume. but I don't actually want to see the volume, but transfer the color from the "density -> color" operation to the mesh inside.

For clarification: while the color seems only green, it isn't. There is a color gradient. so I can't simply assign a color.